# Keeping rows in a dataframe which fulfills multiple constraint

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
> sampledput
           V1                                     V2             V3
1  GSM1010983                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
2  GSM1120330                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
3  GSM1120331                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
4  GSM1282348                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
5  GSM1282357                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
6   GSM906416                                adipose ChIP-Seq input
7   GSM906394                                adipose        H3K27ac
8  GSM1010958                                adipose       mRNA-Seq
9  GSM1120304                                adipose       mRNA-Seq
10 GSM1120305                                adipose       mRNA-Seq
11  GSM621443 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells ChIP-Seq input
12  GSM621420 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells       H3K27me3
13  GSM621446 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells       H3K36me3
14  GSM621418 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells        H3K4me1
15  GSM621458 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells        H3K4me3
16  GSM670020 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells         H3K9ac
17  GSM621398 adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells        H3K9me3
```

I want to keep those rows where value in column `V2` stays same (e.g, `adipose`) while values in column `V3` should contain `Bisulfite-Seq` `H3K27ac`, `ChIP-Seq input` and `mRNA-Seq`.If there are duplicate values in `V3` then just take 1 of them, as you can see I am selecting only one row  that has value `mRNA-Seq` and `Bisulfite-Seq` So in this case I will get the output as:

```
5  GSM1282357                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
6   GSM906416                                adipose ChIP-Seq input
7   GSM906394                                adipose        H3K27ac
8  GSM1010958                                adipose       mRNA-Seq
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 16L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 12L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 14L, 15L, 9L), .Label = c("GSM1010958", 
"GSM1010983", "GSM1120304", "GSM1120305", "GSM1120330", "GSM1120331", 
"GSM1282348", "GSM1282357", "GSM621398", "GSM621418", "GSM621420", 
"GSM621443", "GSM621446", "GSM621458", "GSM670020", "GSM906394", 
"GSM906416"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("adipose", 
"adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("Bisulfite-Seq", 
    "ChIP-Seq input", "H3K27ac", "H3K27me3", "H3K36me3", "H3K4me1", 
    "H3K4me3", "H3K9ac", "H3K9me3", "mRNA-Seq"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the first four rows satisfy your constraint? The value in `V2` is `adipose` and the value in `V3` contains `Bisulfite-Seq`

Comment: @ZachTurn Yes, you are right, they will also be in the output.

Comment: @ZachTurn Actually what I want here is to remove duplicates and just consider 1 of that category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: "Better" Solution**

I actually like this one better because I think the code is more logical:

```
library(dplyr)
sampledput %>% group_by(V2) %>% 
    filter(all(c("Bisulfite-Seq","H3K27ac","ChIP-Seq input","mRNA-Seq") %in%  V3)) %>%
    distinct(V2,V3)

Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: V2 [1]

          V1      V2             V3
      (fctr)  (fctr)         (fctr)
1 GSM1010983 adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
2  GSM906416 adipose ChIP-Seq input
3  GSM906394 adipose        H3K27ac
4 GSM1010958 adipose       mRNA-Seq
```

This will test that all of your desired V3 values are contained within each value of V2. Then it will still filter out any duplicates.

**Original Solution**

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
sampledput %>% group_by(V2) %>% 
    filter(V3 %in% c("Bisulfite-Seq","H3K27ac","ChIP-Seq input","mRNA-Seq")) %>%
    distinct(V2,V3) %>% filter(length(unique(V3))==4)

Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: V2 [2]

          V1                                     V2             V3
      (fctr)                                 (fctr)         (fctr)
1 GSM1010983                                adipose  Bisulfite-Seq
2  GSM906416                                adipose ChIP-Seq input
3  GSM906394                                adipose        H3K27ac
4 GSM1010958                                adipose       mRNA-Seq
```

Note though that when performing the `distinct(V2,V3)` it will grab whichever is the *first* occurrence of that duplicate. In your desired output you list `GSM1282357` whereas my solution returns `GSM1010983`. Not sure if this is a concern for you.

You'll have to test that this generalizes to your whole data set, but it does produce your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a confusion, the output should not be containing the last row, because in case of `adipose derived mesenchymal stem cells` in `V2`, the `V3` does not contains `mRNA-Seq`. Only those rows in `V2` should be kept which fulfills all of the 4 conditions.

Comment: Yes, any distinct value from V2 or V3 is not an issue.

Comment: Hello, I am stuck with this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501840/dataframe-processing) Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little too simple but...

```
library(dplyr)
result <- sampledput %>% group_by(V2, V3) %>% summarise(V1 = V1[length(V1)])
```

This returns the last GSM for each group like your ideal output.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sampledput)[,  .(V1 = last(V1)), .(V2, V3)]
```