# Dataframe processing

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe, which I read by `Match <- read.table("Match.txt", sep="", fill =T, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "", header = F)` and looks like this:

```
> ab
           V1       V2  V3                       V4 V5    V6 V7    V8 V9               V10
1  Inspecting sequence  ID chr1:173244300-173244500       NA       NA                     
2   V$ATF3_Q6        |  19                      (-)  | 0.877  | 0.622  |    aagtccCATCAggg
3   V$ATF3_Q6        |  34                      (-)  | 0.788  | 0.655  |    agggaaCGACAcag
4   V$ATF3_Q6        | 102                      (+)  | 0.738  | 0.685  |    cccTGAGCttagga
5  V$CEBPB_01        |  24                      (+)  | 0.950  | 0.882  |    ccatcagGGAAGgg
72   V$YY1_01        | 117                      (+)  | 0.996  | 0.984  | acttCCCATcttttaag
73 Inspecting sequence  ID chr1:173244350-173244550       NA       NA                     
74  V$ATF3_Q6        |  52                      (+)  | 0.738  | 0.685  |    cccTGAGCttagga
75  V$ATF3_Q6        | 160                      (+)  | 0.862  | 0.687  |    gtcTGACCtggaga
76 V$CEBPB_01        |  57                      (+)  | 0.966  | 0.958  |    agcttagGAAACtt
```

It contains million of such repetition, where first line is: `Inspecting sequence  ID chr1:173244300-173244500` and then some value as can be seen above. I want to process it keeping following things in mind:

1. Extract the first line, break it on `:` and `-` so I will get three columns like: `chr1  173244300  173244500`
2. The 4th column should contain the V1$Row2 1st element, splitted on `$` and `_` and just take the 2nd index which will be `ATF3`, like this I have  30 definite (lets call them names) cases, some will be observed while others not in each case (1 case is from Row 1 to row 72, second start from row 73).
3. If that name appears in 1 case then value `B` will be assigned to that column, if not value `U` will be assigned

So based on my input, I want to get the following output:

```
chr     start       stop        ATF3  CEBPB  YY1    ..(All which appear e.g from row 1 to 72, ignoring duplicates)
chr1    173244300   173244500   B     B      B  
chr1    173244350   173244550   B     B      U
```

I want a fix no.of column in the header (I know they are 32 such names) so if they appear in one case `B` will be assigned, otherwise `U` will be assigned.

If anybody can help me in doing this, it will be a great help.

Here is the dput of this sample dataframe:

```
> ab <- dput(Match[c(1:5,72:76), ])
structure(list(V1 = c("Inspecting", "V$ATF3_Q6", "V$ATF3_Q6", 
"V$ATF3_Q6", "V$CEBPB_01", "V$YY1_01", "Inspecting", "V$ATF3_Q6", 
"V$ATF3_Q6", "V$CEBPB_01"), V2 = c("sequence", "|", "|", "|", 
"|", "|", "sequence", "|", "|", "|"), V3 = c("ID", "19", "34", 
"102", "24", "117", "ID", "52", "160", "57"), V4 = c("chr1:173244300-173244500", 
"(-)", "(-)", "(+)", "(+)", "(+)", "chr1:173244350-173244550", 
"(+)", "(+)", "(+)"), V5 = c("", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|", "", 
"|", "|", "|"), V6 = c(NA, 0.877, 0.788, 0.738, 0.95, 0.996, 
NA, 0.738, 0.862, 0.966), V7 = c("", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|", 
"", "|", "|", "|"), V8 = c(NA, 0.622, 0.655, 0.685, 0.882, 0.984, 
NA, 0.685, 0.687, 0.958), V9 = c("", "|", "|", "|", "|", "|", 
"", "|", "|", "|"), V10 = c("", "aagtccCATCAggg", "agggaaCGACAcag", 
"cccTGAGCttagga", "ccatcagGGAAGgg", "acttCCCATcttttaag", "", 
"cccTGAGCttagga", "gtcTGACCtggaga", "agcttagGAAACtt")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10"), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

given your input file in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38563400/selection-of-particular-indices-from-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment64524983_38563400) as `/c/tmp.txt`

And this awk script saved as `SO-38563400.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
 OFS="\t" # Set the output separator
 i=0 # Just to init the counter and be sure to start at 1 later
}
 {
 #print $0
 }
/Inspecting sequence ID/ { # Changing sequence, initialize new entry with start and end
  split($4,arr,"[:-]") # split the string in fields, split on : and -
  seq[i++,"chr"]=arr[1] # Save the chr part and increase the sequence beforehand
  seq[i,"start"]=arr[2] # save the start date
  seq[i,"end"]=arr[3] # Save the end date
}

/V[$][^_]+_.*/ { # V line type,
  split($1,arr,"[$_]") # Split on $ and underscore
  seq[i,arr[2]]="B" # This has been seen, setting to B
  seq[i,"print"]=1
  names[arr[2]]++ # Save the name for output
  # (and count occurences, just for fun, well mainly because an int is cheaper to store)
  # Main reason is it allow a quicker access toa rray keys ant END block
}

END {
  head=sprintf("char%sstart%sstop",OFS,OFS,OFS)
  for (h in names) {
    head=sprintf("%s%s%s",head,OFS,h)
  }
  print(head)
  for (l=1; l<i; l++) { # loop over each line/sequence
    line=sprintf("%s%s%s%s%s",seq[l,"chr"],OFS,seq[l,"start"],OFS,seq[l,"end"])
    for (h in names) {
      if (seq[l,h]=="B") line=sprintf("%s%s%s",line,OFS,"B")
      else line=sprintf("%s%s%s",line,OFS,"U")
    }
    if (seq[l,"print"]) print line
  }
}
```

Passing this command:

```
awk -f SO-38563400.awk /c/tmp.txt > /c/Rtable.txt
```

Gives:

```
$ cat /c/Rtable.txt
char    start   stop    STAT3   ATF3    TEAD4   GATA3   JUND    HNF4A   FOXA2   MAX     CEBPB   SPI1    GABPA   CMYC    P300    E2F1    CTCF    ATF2
chr22   16049850        16050050        B       B       U       B       U       B       B       U       U       U       U       U       B       B       U       B
chr22   16049900        16050100        B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B       B
```

And then reading in r:

```
> x <- read.table("/c/Rtable.txt", sep="\t",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header=T)
> x
char    start     stop STAT3 ATF3 TEAD4 GATA3 JUND HNF4A FOXA2 MAX CEBPB SPI1 GABPA CMYC P300 E2F1 CTCF ATF2
1 chr22 16049850 16050050     B    B     U     B    U     B     B   U     U    U     U    U    B    B    U    B
2 chr22 16049900 16050100     B    B     B     B    B     B     B   B     B    B     B    B    B    B    B    B
```

Please disregard the setup with `/c/` paths, this could work on windows or linux, there's port of `awk` under windows, I suggest using linux for large files due to the operating system capacities on file streaming.

We can save far more memory by not reading the whole file before printing results, but this need a fixed set of "names" but you've been too lazy to extract the names by yourself and just sent me a bunch of entries, exercice is left to you to adapt, make the list in BEGIN block, use it as entries for each seq, and on each new seq print the previous result before processing.

I hope next time you'll take some time to bake a proper question and that you'll understand you have to make some efforts for others to help you, specially after a flow of comments asking you to improve your question.

Comment: I will start looking in to the solution but first would like to thanks for your time.

Comment: @Newbie You're welcome, I'm convinced R is not a solution for everything, specially to transform weird datas in something usable. But I'm on the the fence this is not an XY problem, trying to solve something induced by previous steps which may be done in another way, hard to guess without the full picture obviously and that's not criticism, I assume you have no control on the entry file.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and answer. I have tried it on my sample file and it worked perfectly, now waiting for the result since last 10 minutes when applied on original file which is 6 gb. I want to change output separator, which I can do by `OFS='\t'` and secondly, is it possible to remove all the rows which contains "U" in every column (column 4 onwards)? I was not getting the idea how can I do that.

Comment: So, in this case row 1:6 and 9 will be removed. I know how to do this in R but I think it will be better if implemented in this awk code.

Comment: @Newbie yes, it's doable to make a conditional around the printing, if there's at least 1 present, then print the line, then not, this mean setting a 'print' field to the line, setting it to true when we find a 'name', editing to reflect this change

Comment: @Newbie done the modification for tabs and filtering

Comment: I was trying to make a few changes in your awk code, in order to get a different type of output but I am unable to obtain my desired result. I need my output in following style: `chr22:16050016-16050028 ATF2` `chr22:16050014-16050028 ATF3` so, now instead of getting one range and listing all of the lines coming under it (just once). I want to add in given range's start value  (i.e 16049850 in chr22:16049850-16050050) the value in the 2nd column of all lines under it and the end value will be a count of last column in the sub lines (e.g. aggaCTTCAgaa which are 12 letters).

Comment: It will be a great help if you can guide me how to modify the awk code to get this kind of output. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Newbie It may worth a new question, I'm unsure of what is your desired output exactly here, open a new question with sample input and corresponding sample output, show what you tried in awk and link to this one for background on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best use of `stringr` or `tidyr`, but this can be done in the hadleyverse in a somewhat readable manner...

The logic flow is:

- Determine the group by using `tidyr::fill` with `ifelse("Inspecting", rowname, NA)`.
- Mutate the fields to what you wanted
- Use reshape (`dcast`) to get the format that you want.

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)

is_in <- function(v1part) {
  return(ifelse(length(v1part) > 0, "B", "U"))
}

ab1<- ab %>% 
  add_rownames() %>%
  mutate(rowname = ifelse(V1=="Inspecting", rowname, NA),
         V4a = ifelse(V4 == "(-)" | V4 == "(+)", NA, V4),

         chr = str_extract_all(ab$V4, "^chr[^:]+", simplify = T)[,1],
         chr = ifelse(chr=="", NA, chr),

         start = str_split_fixed(V4a, ":|-", 3)[,2],
         start = ifelse(start=="", NA, start), 

         stop = str_split_fixed(V4a, ":|-", 3)[,3],
         stop = ifelse(stop=="", NA, stop),

         V1part = str_split_fixed(V1, "\\$|_", 3)[,2]) %>%
  fill(rowname, .direction="down") %>% 
  group_by(rowname) %>%
  fill(chr, .direction="down") %>%
  fill(start, .direction="down") %>%
  fill(stop, .direction="down") %>%
  dcast(chr+start+stop ~ V1part, fun.aggregate=is_in)

> ab1
   chr     start      stop Var.4 ATF3 CEBPB YY1
1 chr1 173244300 173244500     B    B     B   B
2 chr1 173244350 173244550     B    B     B   U
```

Comment: What is this column Var.4 ? Can I remove it from final df ?

Comment: Yeah you can, not sure what happend there

Comment: There are also entries where in 1 case there exist only `Inspecting sequence ID   chr1:0-200` without any data below, can I filter such entries out by any means?

Comment: Something like this can also work: `cd <- ab1[!which(ab1$ARID3A:ab1$YY1 == "U"),]` where I tell it to not include those rows in which a range of column, all contains the same value *U*

Comment: Or something like if after 3rd column every row contains the letter "U" then remove that row. so in this case row having values: `chr1 100 300 U U U U` will be removed from ab1.

Comment: Can you please respond to my questions? An other important thing is I also want the V10 column in the output df. How can I do that?

Comment: Another problem with this solution is memory consumption. as my initial df file is 30 gb and I am using a cluster node having 100 gb of RAM still I am getting **caught segfault, memory not mapped error**

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but it should work (Your data has a column with "|"... I named it df):

```
cond <- which(!df$V2 == "|")
new_df <- data.frame(chr=character(length(cond)), start=character(length(cond)), stop=character(length(cond)))

for (i in 1:length(cond)) {
  line <- df[cond[i], ]
  var <- unlist(strsplit(line$V4, split = ":"))
  var2 <- unlist(strsplit(var[2], split = "-"))
  new_df$chr[i] <- var[1]
  new_df$start[i] <- var2[1]
  new_df$stop[i] <- var2[2]
  for (k in (i+1):(cond[i+1]-1)) {
    # Your code using name <- df$V1 (Use strsplit again)
    # df[i, name] <- ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what do you mean by `# Your code using name <- df$V1 (Use strsplit again)
    # df[i, name] <- ...` Can you please give an answer which is reproducible. Thank you.

Comment: The system is the same as before with `var` and `var2`. Now just take `$` and `_` as `split` arg.

Comment: @cristoph I am sorry I am unable to understand what you are saying, can you please edit this change in your answer. It will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I showed you how to use `strsplit`. How did you try to split `V1$Row2` on `$` and `_`? What does not work?

Comment: Can you please help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236519/replacing-for-loop-with-foreach-loop/49237000?noredirect=1#comment85479099_49237000) of replacing for loops with foreach loop or parSapply. Thanks.